# yii CJuiDatePicker hide text box

Tags: php, yii

How do I hide the text box in CJuiDatePicker in yii. I could not find any option to hide the text box. I would just like to show the `buttonImage`.
I tried all these options but no results.

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker', array(
                            'model'=>$model,
                                'attribute'=>'date_first',
                                'options'=>array(
                                'showAnim'=>'fold',
                                'dateFormat'=>'dd-M-yy',
                                'maxDate'=>'+0',
                                'minDate'=>'-3M',
                                'buttonImage'=>Yii::app()->baseUrl.'/ui/images/cal.gif',
                                'buttomImageOnly'=>true,
                                'buttonText'=>'Select',
                                'showOn'=>'button',
                                'showButtonPanel'=>false,
                                'disabled'=>true,
                                  'htmlOptions'=>array(
                                        //'style'=>'hide;'
                                    ),),true)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can attach the result to a hidden field with the 'altField' option. See my example below:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker', array(
    'name'=>'datepicker_field'
    'options'=>array(
        'showAnim'=>'fold',
        'dateFormat'=>'dd-M-yy',
        'maxDate'=>'+0',
        'minDate'=>'-3M',
        'buttonImage'=>Yii::app()->baseUrl.'/ui/images/cal.gif',
        'buttomImageOnly'=>true,
        'buttonText'=>'Select',
        'showOn'=>'button',
        'showButtonPanel'=>false,
        'disabled'=>true,
        'altField' => '#hidden-date',
    )
));

echo $form->hiddenField($model, 'date_first', array('id'=>'#hidden-date'));
```

I'm not sure if this removes the text field as well, if not you can easily 'hide' it using css (you have to double check if the id is correct):

```
input#datepicker_field {
   display: none;
}
```

This way your input field is gone, and is stored in a hidden field.

Comment: I was able to achieve it with css, I am yet to try your first solution, will revert back once tested.